# Normed vector space algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $f:X\rightarrow R$ defined as $f(x)=\lVert x\lVert$ is a continuous function, where $X$ is a normed space. ($f:X\rightarrow Y$ is said to be continuous at $x\in X$, where $X,Y$ are normed spaces.)

Comment: The explanation of what continuous means seems to be missing some parts.

Comment: In order for $X$ to be a normed linear space, a norm $||\cdot ||$ has to be defined to satisfy the requirements of a normed linear space.  Your $f$ is defined to be that norm.  It is unclear what is to be assumed and what is to be proved in this problem setup.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y$ be any member of $X$, and let $\varepsilon \in (0,\infty)$. Define $\delta:=\varepsilon$. Then, for every $x \in X$ such that $\|x - y\|<\delta$ we have, by the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality),
$$
|f(y) - f(x)| = |\|y\| - \|x\|| \overset{\text{rev. triangle}}{\leq} \| y - x\| < \delta = \varepsilon.
$$